# License/Extract fonts for website being migrated from SquareSpace

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, squarespace

We're migrating a SquareSpace site to another CMS. We're keeping the same site design and code. It seems as though the site is using fonts licensed through fonts.com. What's the best way to determine what these fonts are and license them properly for use outside of Squarespace? Some of the fonts defined I'm unable to find equivalents for. For example, I know the site is using the following fonts:

- Gill Sans W01 Medium
- Gill Sans W01 Light
- .. and possibly more

Any help anyone can provide would be great.

Comment: Why not just buy Gill Sans? It's all of a whopping $29. http://www.fonts.com/font/monotype-imaging/gill-sans

Comment: Definitely not opposed to buying it at all. I'm happy to buy it! I've found "Gill Sans", but not "Gill Sans W01 Medium" and "Gill Sans W01 Light". I'm concerned that the font won't be exactly the same.